# How to combine two procs into one?

Tags: ruby, function-composition

Just wondering if there's a syntax shortcut for taking two procs and joining them so that output of one is passed to the other, equivalent to:

```
a = ->(x) { x + 1 }
b = ->(x) { x * 10 }
c = ->(x) { b.( a.( x ) ) }
```

This would come in handy when working with things like `method(:abc).to_proc` and `:xyz.to_proc`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More sugar, *not really recommended in production code*

```
class Proc
  def *(other)
    ->(*args) { self[*other[*args]] }
  end
end

a = ->(x){x+1}
b = ->(x){x*10}
c = b*a
c.call(1) #=> 20
```

Comment: Very nice! Why wouldn't you recommend it?

Comment: Re-opening built-in classes (like Proc), is always risky due to other libraries possibly doing the same, or future changes to Ruby itself.

Comment: I'm surprised it's not in the standard library somewhere. Seems like a fairly useful thing.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = Proc.new { |x| x + 1 }
b = Proc.new { |x| x * 10 }
c = Proc.new { |x| b.call(a.call(x)) }
```

Comment: Please explain what sugar is missing from this answer?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear: you're given `a` and `b`. You need to get `c`. You can of course write a new proc, but I'm wondering if there's a shorter way, like `b.wrap a` or something.

Answer (score 2):

you could create a union operation like so

```
class Proc
   def union p
      proc {p.call(self.call)}
   end
end
def bind v
   proc { v}
end
```

then you can use it like this

```
 a = -> (x) { x + 1 }
 b = -> (x) { x * 10 }
 c = -> (x) {bind(x).union(a).union(b).call}
```

Answer (score 1):

An updated answer. Proc composition is already available in Ruby 2.6. There are two methods `<<` and `>>`, differing in the order of the composition. So now you can do

```
##ruby2.6
a = ->(x) { x + 1 }
b = ->(x) { x * 10 }
c = a >> b
c.call(1) #=> 20
```