# Concatenate procs while retaining context reevaluation capabilities

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, proc

I want to concatenate the bodies of two procs. But unlike [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799788/how-to-combine-two-procs-into-one), there is a twist. The resulting proc should retain the original procs' *instance_eval*-ability.

It might sound a little confusing, so here is my use case.

---

I'm implementing another language as internal DSL in Ruby. An oversimplified implementation:

```
class Interpreter
  def self.run(&program)
    Interpreter.new.instance_eval(&program)
  end

  def initialize
    @variables = {}
  end

  def assign_variable(name, value)
    @variables[name] = value
  end

  def display(name)
    puts @variables[name]
  end
end

Interpreter.run do
  assign_variable :foo, 42
  display :foo
end
```

If I split the body of the proc into two other:

```
assignment = proc { assign_variable :foo, 42 }
printing   = proc { display :foo }
combined   = proc { assignment.call; printing.call }

Interpreter.run(&combined)
```

It wont work because the `combined` proc is being *instance_eval*-ed, but the `assignment` and `printing` procs are evaluated in the context of the place they were defined.

The reason I want to split the original proc is so that I can DRY my tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
combined = proc {
  instance_eval &assignment
  instance_eval &printing
}
```

But I wouldn't be surprised if someone comes up with something more idiomatic

Comment: I thought it will be trying to `instance_eval` in the context it was defined. Works like a charm. Should have tried it!